# Include month if not there in php array

Tags: php, date

I have an array  like this in php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => April-2014
            [total_booking] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => May-2014
            [total_booking] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => June-2014
            [total_booking] => 25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => October-2013
            [total_booking] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [month] => July-2014
            [total_booking] => 4
        )

)
```

I have to make this array

if i selected two months `from_month` , `to_month`  if there are no any months in this array it should be included  eg:

i have selected from_month 2014 feb to_month 2014 may . but if in my array only 2014 feb, 2014 april,2014 may only so iwat to include 2014 march in correct place.
like this

```
 Array
            (
                [month] => March-2014
                [total_booking] => 0
            )
```

this is my code

```
 foreach ($newarray as $month => total_booking) {
         //sorting 

      }



     foreach ($newarray as $month => total_booking) {
             //if there is no month in array betwean to_month and from_month it    

            should be  included in correct place as sorted

          }
```

Comment: You are asking how to sort it?

Comment: @putvande no..,,,.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The best way is to take reference from the start date and end date you inputted and look it up in the master array..**

Here it is(please scroll for answer)

```
$your_array=array
   (
     array
        (
            'month' => 'April-2014',
            'total_booking' => 2
        ),

    array
        (
            'month' => 'May-2014',
            'total_booking' => 5
        ),

    array
        (
            'month' => 'June-2014',
            'total_booking' => 25
        ),

    array
        (
            'month' => 'October-2013',
            'total_booking' => 1
        ),

    array
        (
            'month' => 'July-2014',
            'total_booking' => 4
        )

);
        $start_date="Jan 1 2013";
        $end_date="Dec 31 2014";
        $timestamp1=strtotime($start_date);
        $timestamp2=strtotime($end_date);
        for($i=$timestamp1;$i<$timestamp2;$i=$i+24*60*60){
            //echo $i;
            $gapmonth[]=date('F-Y',$i);
        }
        $gapmonth=array_unique($gapmonth);

        //convert $dataS(ORIGINAL ARRAY) to one dimentional array so the life will be easier
        foreach($your_array as $val){
            $derived_val[$val['month']]=$val['total_booking'];
        }

        foreach($gapmonth as $val){
            if(array_key_exists($val,$derived_val)){
                $total_booking=$derived_val[$val];
            }
            else{
                $total_booking=0;
            }
            $finaldate[]=array('month'=>$val,'total_booking'=>$total_booking);
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($finaldate);
```

OUTPUTS

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => January-2013
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => February-2013
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => March-2013
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => April-2013
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [month] => May-2013
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [month] => June-2013
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [month] => July-2013
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [month] => August-2013
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [month] => September-2013
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [month] => October-2013
            [total_booking] => 1
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [month] => November-2013
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [month] => December-2013
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [month] => January-2014
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [month] => February-2014
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [month] => March-2014
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [month] => April-2014
            [total_booking] => 2
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [month] => May-2014
            [total_booking] => 5
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [month] => June-2014
            [total_booking] => 25
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [month] => July-2014
            [total_booking] => 4
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [month] => August-2014
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [month] => September-2014
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [month] => October-2014
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [month] => November-2014
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [month] => December-2014
            [total_booking] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: I suggest you delete your array in the first codeblock and use a name like `$your_array`, I almost missed that you actually had code (I though you did it by hand;) )

Comment: SORRY SIR .. I DIDNT GET U .. I AM POOR IN ENGLISH :)

Comment: I did it myself. Please use lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through it and test if values are missing:

```
$prev_month = false;
foreach($your_array as $k=>$values){
    if($prev_month!==false){ // first itteration will be empty, dont do useless checks
        // Test if themonth after the previous month matches this one
        if( $prev_month+1 !== $values['month']  ){
            // FILL IN THE BLANKS
            // splice in at position $thisIndex (<- this you'll have to do)
            array_splice( $prev_month, $thisIndex-1, 0, $newDateBookingsArray); // -1, we want it before this item!
            // (dont forget to loop in case more than 1 items miss)
        }

    }
    $prev_month = $values['month']; // save value for next round
}
```

*Edit: TS first asked to sort the array, the code to use a custom sort can be found in the edits of this post.*

Comment: actually  this is not my requirment i want to include all months betwean this date as sorted.  for eg:  i have selected `from_month` 2014 feb `to_month`  2014 may   . but if in my array only  `2014 feb, 2014 april,2014 may`  only   so iwat to include `2014 march` in correct place

Comment: You asked to "**1. make this array sorted**". The 2nd part of my answer answers part 2 of your question

Comment: that means i want to include as sorted. my mistake..my qn was confusing.. edited my qn

Comment: I've editted my post. Included a method to add a value at the point you want, this way resroting isnt needed